# Xamrin UWP Release causes weird NullReferenceException (System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes)

Tags: debugging, release, nullreferenceexception, xamarin.uwp

```
public static class CryptoHelper {
    // This size of the IV (in bytes) must = (keysize / 8).  Default keysize is 256, so the IV must be
    // 32 bytes long.  Using a 16 character string here gives us 32 bytes when converted to a byte array.
    private const string initVector = "pemgail9uzpgzl88";
    // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm
    private static int keysize = 256;

    private static int getKeySize()
    {
        return 256;
    }

    //Encrypt
    //public static byte[] EncryptString( string plainText, string passPhrase ) {
    public static byte[] EncryptString(string toEncrypt, string salt)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[126];
        try
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), null);

            Debug.WriteLine(CryptoHelper.getKeySize());
            Debug.WriteLine(password.ToString());
            keyBytes = password.GetBytes(256 / 8);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        

        
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return cipherTextBytes;
    }
 ........
```

**The call to "password.GetBytes(256 / 8);" results in a non catchable NullReferenceException**
This happens only when the UWP App is in Release mode; UWP Debug as well as Andorid and IOS are fine.

Also I get a weird Debug Message:

> "this.**_hash**" war "null".

**or**

> "this.**_hash**" was "null". (translated)

Here you can see it in action
[VS2019 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfW2s.png)

To repuduce this issue the inputs for the function are:

**toEncrypt**   "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE3MDAyMTEyfQ.C0CaGgfibM4z55MoANI2CiohUyew09r3_D_TpcQ6n1c8LmQd8BusSyF1SMEIQ3cO5uxE9Tnau0ZAT6D3kN3NcQ"

**salt**
"9x83m74tzrx9387x4mz98374zt90x8m273z948734z59"

**Cause I cant see the detailed cause of this problem there it is basilcy not possible to get a workaround for this.**

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make the same code work. The solution I found was to replace:

```
PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), null);
```

with:

```
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678"));
```

and also add this:

```
symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```